# How to filter Model from select using the selected value from other select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am using a `simple_form_for` with select from Model. I want to filter some of my select using the selected value from other select.

here is my code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @location do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :state_id, State.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }
  <%= f.select :country_id, Country.where(state_id: params[:state_id]).map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }
  <%= f.select :town_id, Town.where(country_id: params[:country_id]).map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }
  <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

params[`field`] is no value yet.

Can you please help me on this? or do you have any other best solution for this?

Comment: Are you trying to implement dynamic dropdown?

Comment: I don't know yet about dynamic dropdown. I just checked your url suggestion. I think like that, is what I need.